# Data mining for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas

I start in data analysis and I encounter a problem on an exercise to recover on kaggle: file 'ENBsv' I import my data, determine the correlation, create a new column in my dataframe which totals my target variables

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import model_selection
    from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
    from sklearn import ensemble
    from sklearn import svm
    from sklearn import neighbors
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier


    df = pd.read_csv('ENB.csv')
    df.columns= ["relative_compactness","surface_area","wall_area","roof_area","overall_height","orientaion",
               "glazing_area","glazing_area_dist","heating_load","cooling_load"]

    df.head()

   corr =df.corr(method = 'pearson')
   plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
   sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True, cmap='Greens');

   df['total_charges'] = pd.Series([1]).astype(dtype=float)
   df['total_charges'] = df['heating_load'] + df['cooling_load']
```

I have to instantiate new variable 'charges_classes' split the buildings into 4 distinct classes with the label 0,1,2,3 according to the 3 quantiles of the new variable created. But I have to look and seek I can not find a solution, someone can help me here is what I did:

```
      charge_classes = pd.get_dummies(df['total_charges'])
      charge_classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
df['charge_classes'] = pd.qcut(df['total_charges'], 4, labels=False)
```